# Required is not defined, when using electron, how do I fix it? (already tried nodeintegration)

Tags: node.js, electron, require

so I am using electron to build an app. 
I need to use "fs", but since I can't require it, because require doesn't work in electron, I'm stuck.

I already tried settings "nodeItegration: true" but it still won't work, also have I tried using a preload script but it still doesn't work. Maybe I have done something wrong with the preload script?

Code is below.

main.js

```
const electron = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let MainWindow;

app.on("ready", function(){

MainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntergration: true,
        preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js')
    }
});
MainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
    protocol:"file:",
    slashes: true
}));

});

console.log(require.resolve('electron'))
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CommendBot UI</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <button class="safeData-button" onclick="safeData()">Safe</button>

  </div>

</div>

<script>
  // You can also require other files to run in this process

</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="preload.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

preload.js

```
    function safeData() {
    var fs = require("fs");
    var sampleObject = {
        .......(some JSON data)
    }


        fs.writeFile("./object.json", JSON.stringify(sampleObject, null, 4), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            };
            console.log("File has been created");
        });
}
```

So whats basically not working, is my function call from my "Safe" button, which is calling the function to fs.writeFile and write a JSON file.

I am sorry for posting the whole code, not sure if it is more helpful or not.

Thanks for answers, in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely a simple typo:

```
MainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true, // Note spelling!
        preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js')
    }
});
```